# Possible to get equivalent MySQL bin log position on another server?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

Let's say we have three MySQL servers, `mysql1`, `mysql2` and `mysql3`. Replication is set up such that `mysql3` is the slave of `mysql2`, and `mysql2` is the slave of `mysql1`.

At some point I take a dump of `mysql2` and record the binlog file and position of it by running `show master status;`. Is there a way to find the equivalent binlog file and position on `mysql1` - for example so that I could load up the dump and continue replicating from `mysql1` instead of `mysql2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this by examining the log files using `mysqlbinlog`.

Given the following master log position on `mysql2`:

```
Master log file = mysql-bin.003151
Master log pos  = 46678888
```

I opened the log file:

```
mysql2> mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.003151 | less
```

And searched for the position (46678888).

```
# at 46678861
#170301 12:15:33 server id 2  end_log_pos 46678888
  Xid = 12652204449 COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 46678888
#170301 12:15:36 server id 2  end_log_pos 46678967
  Query   thread_id=414919 69      exec_time=1     error_code=0
  SET TIMESTAMP=1488370536/*!*/; BEGIN /*!*/;
# at 46678967
```

The nearby line of `SET TIMESTAMP=1488370536` looked like a good candidate to search for in the corresponding log on `mysql1`. So I opened up the master log file on `mysql1` (there were multiple to choose from, but I went with the one with the closest timestamp to that on the slave, you might have to try a few files):

```
mysql1> mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.002966 | less
```

And searched for `SET TIMESTAMP=1488370536`. This is what I found:

```
# at 46236234
#170301 12:15:33 server id 2  end_log_pos 46236261
  Xid = 88972150 COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 46236261
#170301 12:15:36 server id 2  end_log_pos 46236325
  Query   thread_id=414919    69      exec_time=1     error_code=0
  SET TIMESTAMP=1488370536/*!*/; BEGIN /*!*/;
# at 46236325
```

I checked surrounding lines to ensure I'd got the right place and then used the corresponding `end_log_pos` (in this case 46236261) as the new log position. Therefore my master log position on `mysql1` is:

```
Master log file = mysql-bin.002966
Master log pos  = 46236261
```

It's probably possible to automate this process somewhat, but to be honest it was very quick and easy to do it manually (and I don't expect to have to do again much if at all) - it's taken longer to write up the process than actually do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the --dump-slave option on mysqldump:

--dump-slave[=#]    This causes the binary log position and filename of the
                      master to be appended to the dumped data output. Setting
                      the value to 1, will printit as a CHANGE MASTER command
                      in the dumped data output; if equal to 2, that command
                      will be prefixed with a comment symbol. This option will
                      turn --lock-all-tables on, unless --single-transaction is
                      specified too (in which case a global read lock is only
                      taken a short time at the beginning of the dump - don't
                      forget to read about --single-transaction below). In all
                      cases any action on logs will happen at the exact moment
                      of the dump.Option automatically turns --lock-tables off.

So to clone a slave with mysqldump, you'd do something like this:

```
mysqldump --all-databases --dump-slave --flush-logs > somedumpfile.sql
```

Then load somedumpfile.sql on the new slave.

Comment: Thanks, that is indeed the way to do it before you make a dump - in my situation though I'd already got the dump and log position on the slave and needed to convert that into the master log position.

Comment: OK, but just FYI, if you do this:  "At some point I take a dump of mysql2 and record the binlog file and position of it by running show master status;" you need to be sure that you were holding FTWRL while dumping and capturing those coordinates or it doesn't really help to figure out the corresponding master coordinates.

Comment: That's true. I wasn't quite telling the truth in the question - I didn't run `show master status` at all, I performed a mysqldump with the `--single-transaction --master-data=2` parameters.

Comment: OK, but you still need --flush-logs  :)